# Magento 2: Add block to cms page with / in the url key trough xml

Tags: magento2, frontend, xml

Magento 2: I'm trying to add a block to a cms page with a layout overwrite. The problem is the url key has a / at the end which can not be removed. So the url key is uber-uns/ If i remove the / as a TEST it works. Any one got a clue how i do this and keep the /?

app/design/frontend/Company/theme-shopname/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_page_view_id_uber-uns.xml (this works as a test without /)
*(file content isn't really relevant for the question)*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="main">
            <container name="home-blocks" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="home-blocks">
                <container name="home-blocks-right-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="home-blocks-right-wrapper"
                           after="-">
                    <container name="home-block-2-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="home-block-2 movies-left"
                               before="-">
                        <block class="Company\HomePageVideo\Block\HomeVideo" name="block-movies-left"
                               template="Company_HomePageVideo::homepage-video.phtml">
                            <container name="home-block-2-text" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="home-block-2-text">
                                <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="home-block-2">
                                    <arguments>
                                        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">home-block-2</argument>
                                    </arguments>
                                </block>
                            </container>
                        </block>
                    </container>
                </container>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure it out. So i ended up making a html block and adding it to the specific page with the pagebuilder.

```
{{block class="Company\HomePageVideo\Block\HomeVideo" name="over-ons-video" template="Company_HomePageVideo::over-ons-video.phtml" area="frontend"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

1)From layout .xml file:

```
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="Promo">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">promo</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

2)From .Phtml File:

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>
```

3)From cms page or block:

```
{{block class="Magento\\Cms\\Block\\Block" block_id="block_identifier"}}
```

I hope this may help you.